# VW Polo (2015) user manual

Tags: vw, polo

Does anyone have a PDF copy that I can download? Lost the original and the dealer seems unable to procure one. 2010 onwards will do although there was a facelift in 2014 so those are better.

Comment: When searching for other auto parts, I normally see search results for manuals on eBay, so that's another place to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to speak to Volkswagen customer service team.  They should be able to assist.  The dealerships ought to be able to order a new owners handbook for you so they can probably explain why this isn't happening.

Their contact details can be found [at this link](http://www.volkswagen.co.uk/need-help/about-us/customer-care)

Answer (score 1):

Get a physical copy at junkyard. They are cheap (and sometimes free). Call around (dont email) and get yourself one. :)